# How to add my personal website in the header of Awesome CV template?

Tags: overleaf, awesome-cv

I am trying to use Awesome CV from overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm) where I want to include my personal porfolio website along with my Phone No., my e-mail, my linkedin account in the header. I have used the particular `\newcommand*{\homepage}[1]{\def\@homepage{#1}}` in awesome-cv.cls and `\homepage{<my website link>}` in resume.tex

While opening up the website from the resume, it throws an error (This site can't be readched, It is not secure) with the wrong link "http://https//mywebsite.netlify.app/" in browser whereas the website should be "https://mywebsite.netlify.app/"

*Ps website has been hidden for personal reasons
[image: My Website]

Comment: I think you made a typo in the URL you wrote. Maybe you missed the `:` and wrote `https//mywebsite.netlify.app`.

Comment: Did you use `\hompage{https://mywebsite.netlify.app}` or did you only use `\hompage{mywebsite.netlify.app}`? Please extend your question to a minimal example we can actually test and use to replicate your issue!